# echo command echo the blank output instead of Variable value in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, bash, 18.04, scripts

can you please help me with very strange situation,

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and running some bash script and my script looks like this.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    FOLDER="$1"
    FILE="$2"

BASENAME=$(/bin/basename "$FOLDER/$FILE" | /bin/sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')

HOST="FTPSERVER"
USER="username"
PASSWORD="pass"
###########################

cd /home/vod/output/
#start=$(date +%s)

ftp -n -v >> /var/log/ftptransfer_hrmxf.log 2>&1 $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
binary
user $USER $PASSWORD
prompt
cd media
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
############### FIXME!!!! #######################

echo "$BASENAME" >> /var/log/videos_done
```

the issue is here that ECHO Command doesn't output the Basename and instead it output the Blank character.

please help me understand what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you So Much.

Comment: Do some troubleshooting. What is the result of `/bin/basename "$FOLDER/$FILE"`? What happens if you put that result through the `sed` command manually? Somewhere along the line the result is blank, but we don't know at which point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `basename` is located in `/usr/bin/basename` NOT where you have it coded in your scripting.
Thus, because the `basename`command has failed (and you have not checked this in your code), the value of the varialble `$BASENAME` is most likely `NULL`.

What I usually do in any scripting is place an explicit PATH at the start of the script.  Something like:

```
 PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
 export PATH
```

It is not immediately clear what the purpose of the `sed` command is.

Also try using the command `bash -uvx scriptname` to examine the expansion and setting of the variables before the command and when the command gets executed.

Comment: yes that was exactly the issue. thank you for the help and suggestion.